# Hibernate Search not returning results

Tags: spring, lucene, hibernate-search

I am building an application with Hibernate Search 4.5.1 and Spring 4.0.5.RELEASE. I am trying to index the following class:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Analyzer(impl= org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer.class)
@Table(name="SONG")
@XmlRootElement(name="song")
public class Song  
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Field(store = Store.YES)
    @Column(name="NAME",  length=255)
    private String name;

    @Field(store = Store.YES)
    @Column(name="ALBUM",  length=255)
    private String album;

    @Field(store = Store.YES)
    @Column(name="ARTIST",  length=255)
    private String artist;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="PATH",  length=255)
    private String path;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="PATH_COVER",  length=255)
    private String cover;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="LAST_VOTE")
    private Date date;

    @Field(store = Store.YES)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name="N_VOTES")
    private int nvotes;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="ACTIVE", nullable=false, columnDefinition="TINYINT(1) default 0")
    private boolean active;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="IMAGE_ID",insertable=true,updatable=true,nullable=false,unique=false)
    private Image image;

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PLAYLIST_ID", nullable = false)
    private PlayList playList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "song")
    private Set<UserVotes> userServices = new HashSet<UserVotes>();
```

I am building a junit test case which looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:jukebox-servlet-test.xml"})
@Transactional
public class SongDaoTest {

     @Autowired
     public I_PlaceDao placeDao;
     @Autowired
     public I_PlayListDao playListDao;
     @Autowired
     public I_SongDao songDao;

     @Before
     public void prepare() throws Exception 
     {
            Operation operation = sequenceOf(CommonOperations.DISABLE_CONTRAINTS, CommonOperations.DELETE_ALL,CommonOperations.INSERT_SONG_DATA, CommonOperations.ENABLE_CONTRAINTS);
            DbSetup dbSetup = new DbSetup(new DriverManagerDestination("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jukebox", "root", "mpsbart"), operation);
            dbSetup.launch();
            FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(placeDao.getSession());
            fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();
     }

    @Test
    @Rollback(false)
    public void searchTest()
    {
        PlayList playList = playListDao.read(1l);
        List<Song> songs = songDao.search(playList, "offspring", 1, 10);
        assertEquals(10, songs.size());
    }
```

The search method implementation is:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Song> search(PlayList playlist, String searchTerm,int page,int limit) 
    {
        FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(getSession());
        QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Song.class).get();
        BooleanQuery luceneQuery = new BooleanQuery();
        luceneQuery.add(queryBuilder.keyword().onFields("name","album","artist").matching("*"+searchTerm+"*").createQuery(), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST); 
        luceneQuery.add(queryBuilder.phrase().onField("playList.place.id").sentence("\""+playlist.getPlace().getId()+"\"").createQuery(), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
        luceneQuery.add(queryBuilder.phrase().onField("playList.id").sentence("\""+playlist.getId()+"\"").createQuery(), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
        // wrap Lucene query in a javax.persistence.Query
        FullTextQuery query = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Song.class);
        org.apache.lucene.search.Sort sort = new Sort(new SortField("n_votes",SortField.INT));
        query.setSort(sort);
        List<Song> songs = query.setFirstResult(page*limit).setMaxResults(limit).list();
        return songs;
    }
```

The test result fails, it does not find any matching object. When using luke lucene I can see that there are results, if I try the query generated by hibernate on luke it does return elements. The query generated by hibernate is: +(name:metallica album:metallica artist:metallica) +playList.place.id:"*1*" +playList.id:"1"

I have also noticed on luke lucene that some index terms have a length up to six characters, for an instance, one song's artist it's "The Offspring" and the terms stored in the index are "the" and "offspr". The first one it's ok, but shouldn't the second term be "offspring". Why is it truncating the name?

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anybody, I was able to fix it by changing the query to this:

```
        FullTextSession fullTextSession = org.hibernate.search.Search.getFullTextSession(getSession());  
    QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Song.class).get();  

    if(searchTerm==null || searchTerm.equals(""))
        searchTerm="*";
    else
        searchTerm="*"+searchTerm+"*";
    Query luceneQuery1 = qb.bool()
            .should(qb.keyword().wildcard().onField("name").matching(searchTerm).createQuery())
            .should(qb.keyword().wildcard().onField("album").matching(searchTerm).createQuery())
            .should(qb.keyword().wildcard().onField("artist").matching(searchTerm).createQuery()).createQuery();
    Query luceneQuery2 = qb.bool()
            .must(qb.keyword().wildcard().onField("playList.place.id").matching(playlist.getPlace().getId()).createQuery())
            .must(qb.keyword().wildcard().onField("playList.id").matching(playlist.getId()).createQuery())
            .createQuery();
    BooleanQuery finalLuceneQuery=new BooleanQuery();
    finalLuceneQuery.add(luceneQuery1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    finalLuceneQuery.add(luceneQuery2, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    FullTextQuery query = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(finalLuceneQuery, Song.class);
    org.apache.lucene.search.Sort sort = new Sort(new SortField("nvotes",SortField.INT,true));
    query.setSort(sort);
    List<Song> songs = query.setFirstResult(page*limit).setMaxResults(limit).list();
```

Answer (score 0):

in case of you have check that field value is null or not null then you must add following line on field where indexing field in class

**@Field(index=Index.YES,analyze=Analyze.NO,store=Store.YES,indexNullAs=Field.DEFAULT_NULL_TOKEN)**

Search on field
if you want null value then 
 booleanQuery.must(qb.keyword().onField("callReminder").matching("*null*").createQuery());

if you don't want null value

booleanQuery.must(qb.keyword().onField("callReminder").matching("*null*").createQuery()).not();

refrence document:http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.1/reference/en-US/html/search-mapping.html#search-mapping-entity